# Spring Data JPA @Query NamedQuery is not working for two @Params

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.2

Only one @Param is passed, it is working well like below, either firstName or lastName. spring-boot version 2.2.0.RELEASE is using.

```java
 @Query(value = "select s from SalesTransaction s where (:firstName is null or LOWER(s.firstName) LIKE LOWER(concat('%',concat(:firstName,'%'))))")
List<SalesTransaction> findFromFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);
```

But if pass two @Params it is throwing the below exception. firstName and lastName are of type TEXT in entity definition. If fistName is passing, lastName is setting as 'null' from Controller and vice-versa.

```java
@Query(value = "select s from SalesTransaction s where (:firstName is null or LOWER(s.firstName) LIKE LOWER(concat('%',concat(:firstName,'%')))) and (:lastName is null or LOWER(s.lastName) LIKE LOWER(concat('%',concat(:lastName,'%'))))")
List<SalesTransaction> findFromFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName,@Param("lastName") String lastName);
```

Exception on runtime:

```
[32m2020-05-11 21:09:17,237[0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m [[34mhttp-nio-8080-exec-5[0;39m] [33morg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper[0;39m: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
[32m2020-05-11 21:09:17,237[0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [[34mhttp-nio-8080-exec-5[0;39m] [33morg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper[0;39m: ERROR: function lower(bytea) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 1324
```

Only one input @Param is working at a time. Please suggest any way to resolve this issue.

Hibernate Generated SQL Query

```
salestrans0_.transaction_ref as transac28_1_ from sales_transaction.sales_transaction salestrans0_ where (? is null or lower(salestrans0_.first_name) like lower(('%'||(?||'%')))) and (? is null or lower(salestrans0_.last_name) like lower(('%'||(?||'%'))))
```

Comment: May be there is no null value in firstName value but null in lastName

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? And also the SQL Hibernate generates, if it generates any?

Comment: salestrans0_.transaction_ref as transac28_1_ from sales_transaction.sales_transaction salestrans0_ where (? is null or lower(salestrans0_.first_name) like lower(('%'||(?||'%')))) and (? is null or lower(salestrans0_.last_name) like lower(('%'||(?||'%'))))

Comment: I converted the JPQL query to Criteria API implementation and it is working now.